# Insert missing letter javascript game

Tags: javascript, html, string, string-comparison

I'm making a language learning game with javascript. I want the user to be able to write the missing letter and the results to be validated through javascript if they are right or wrong.

```
<form>
      De<input id="letterone" type="text" name="latter" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1}">
      ign<input id="lettertwo" type="text" name="latter" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1}">r
      <input type="submit">
</form>
```

My javascript code.

```
if ((getElementById('letterone')==='s') && (getElementById('lettertwo')==='e')) {
    alert('Correct');
}else{
    alert('Wrong');
}
```

Comment: Its `document.getElementById()` and you need to use `.value` property

Comment: I corrected the `document` but it only outputs wrong also when I try the correct values. Also just as soon as the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var lOne = document.getElementById('letterone').value; // get the value of the first input
var lTwo = document.getElementById('lettertwo').value; // get the value of the second

if (lOne === 's') && lTwo === 'e') {
    alert('Correct');
}else{
    alert('Wrong');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are number of errors on your code :

- No 'document' before getElementById
- No 'value' after the object
- No click handler
- Incorrect id while accessing the object
- Using input type=submit causes an unwanted page refresh as [Useless Code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778975/useless-code) comments below.

```js
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if ((document.getElementById('latterone').value==='s') && (document.getElementById('lattertwo').value==='e')) {
    alert('Correct');
  }else{
    alert('Wrong');
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
      De<input type="text" id="latterone" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1}">
      ign<input type="text" id="lattertwo" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1}">r
      <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: One important thing to note here, Bulent used a `click` handler on a `type="button"` element. Buttons do not submit the form, which is important. If it had stayed a `type="submit"` element, the page would reload every time it was pressed; unless you added a `onsubmit` event to the form and called [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in it.